# How to create a loop with an iterator that will run the same command with only a different counter - in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops

How do I create a loop with an iterator that will run the same command that only the counter inside the array will be changed [0] , [1] etc.

Regarding the following code in the "Command Action".
Command = A commands that I running

```
# Get Results
$rest_api_id = COMMAND --query 'items[*].id' --output text
$CharArray = $rest_api_id.Split()
$CharArray

# Loop Iterator
$Counter_All = For ($i=0; $i -le 10; $i++) {
    ($i)
    }
$Counter_All

# Commands Action
Same COMMAND $CharArray[0]
Same COMMAND $CharArray[1]
Same COMMAND $CharArray[2]
Same COMMAND $CharArray[3]
etc.
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the loop you have?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code a little bit and I ended up using the While loop.

```
$rest_api_id = COMMAND --query 'items[*].id' --output text
$CharArray = $rest_api_id.Split()
$CharArray

$counter = 0

DO
{
 CIMMAND $CharArray[$counter]
 $counter
 $counter++

 } While ($counter -le 5)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but I assume you are looking for something like a `foreach` loop

```bsh
foreach ($item in $APIArguments) {
    & myapicall $item
}
```

You can look into more details at `help about_foreach`

Comment: Hi, I know that I need to use the foreach loop, the problem that I can't figure how to run it correctly.
I have the loop iterator that will count from 1 to 10
What I'm asking is how I can run in a loop the same command that will select all the items in the array ? Instead of running each time the same command with different array number.

# Commands Action
Same COMMAND $CharArray[0]
Same COMMAND $CharArray[1]
Same COMMAND $CharArray[2]
Same COMMAND $CharArray[3]
Same COMMAND $CharArray[4]
Same COMMAND $CharArray[5]
etc.